# Data matrix in Rails admin between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I need a matrix between two models.

```
Grade Model
    name

Student model
    name
    gradeId

Course model
    name
    gradeId

Score model
    courseId
    studentId
    note1
    note2
    note3
    note4
    average
```

The relation is:

```
Student 
    belongs_to Grade
    has_many Scores
    has_many Courses, through: Scores

Course 
    belongs_to Grade
    has_many Scores
    has_many Students, through: Scores

Score
    belongs_to Student
    belongs_to Course
```

[image: 1]
This is expected, that can be edited for example in the matrix 1:1 that is note1 belongs to student1 in course1

Comment: Are you going to join two tables? if so, which tables?

Comment: Students and Courses through Scores

Comment: `Student.joins(:courses)`, is this all you need?

Comment: And you need a csv or excel export with this matrix? a read only view? a write view?

Comment: I need a write view.